# Show a div on option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a selection menu (drop down list).

```
<select>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>
```

& the following div which located in somewhere in my page.

```
<div id="somediv">This is a string.</div>
```

I want to display the above div upon selecting the second item of the menu (`id="two"`).

I have 2 questions: **(1)** What is the best way to keep this div hidden by default? I will just add `display:none;` to its styling, but maybe there is a better solution? **(2)** How can I make the div show up when the option of `id="two"` is selected? Any answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer to question (1): `display:none;` works fine use that.

Comment: 1) css, maybe 2) http://api.jquery.com/show/, https://api.jquery.com/change/,,,,

Answer (score 2):

So I wrote a simple jquery script that does what you described. Let me know if it fixes your problem. You can also do this with javascript, but I think jquery works for this just fine. 
http://codepen.io/Francisco104/pen/vEPRgp

```
$('select').change(function(){
  decide($(this));
});
var decide = function (elem) {
    var touch = elem;
  if (touch.val() === 'anything') {
   return $('#somediv').css('display', 'block');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For hiding it by default, using `style="display: none"`is the easiest. You could do it using jquery `$('div#somediv').hide();` but I don't see any benefit to that other than you possibly wanting to keep the show/hide logic together.

Here are two simple solutions using a `change()` event.

**If `div#somediv` should be shown permanently when `option#two` has been selected:**

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'anything') $('div#somediv').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>
<div id="somediv" style="display: none">This is a string.</div>
```

**If `div#somediv` should be shown while `option#two` is selected and disappear if the user selects another option:**

```js
$("select").change(function() {
    $('div#somediv').toggle($(this).val() == 'anything');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>
<div id="somediv" style="display: none">This is a string.</div>
```

You should probably give an `id` to the `select` as well, to make the jQuery selector less brittle.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'd have a class for the div, let's say, `is-hidden` and my CSS will have `.is-hidden { display: none; }`. Then, do the following.

HTML:

```
<div id="somediv" class="is-hidden">This is a string.</div>
```

JS:

```
$div = $("#somediv");
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $div.is(".is-hidden") || $div.addClass("is-hidden");

    //Option 1
    if ($(this).find(":selected")[0].id === "two") {
        $div.removeClass("is-hidden");
    }

    //Option 2 (same as above, but a bit shorter)
    $(this).find(":selected")[0].id === "two" && $div.removeClass("is-hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can hide the div initially giving the **css property** `display:none;` or by setting its **display property** using **javascript** which will run in initial load.

2) You can listen to the **onchange event** of the selectfield and check if value is 'anything' then show the div by **changing** its **display style property** to `block` and `hidden` in other cases.

```js
document.getElementById("somediv").style.display='none';  
var showHideDiv=function(selectField){
  var divElement=document.getElementById("somediv");
if (selectField.value=='anything')
  divElement.style.display='block';
  else
  divElement.style.display='none';  
}
```

```html
<select onchange='showHideDiv(this)'>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>

<div id="somediv">This is a string.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

in your html file:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<select>
  <option id="one" value="something">Car</option>
  <option id="two" value="anything">Plane</option>
</select>
```

You'll need to import the JQuery library (which I show you there right above the `<select>` element) so that you can execute your script.

In your css file:

```
#somediv {
    display: none;
}
```

and finally here is the script that will show the dive when "plane" is selected

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('#somediv').css('display','block');
});
```

Take a look at this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/or2q6vqt/) I made for you.

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest way to hide within HTML**

> `<div hidden>content</div>`

*To display an hidden div*

$(document).ready(function(){

$("select").change(function () {
                $( "select option:selected").each(function(){

```
            if($(this).attr("value")=="anything"){


                $("#somediv").show();

            }
```

});.
});

Answer (score -1):

Display none works.

Have you tried keying into the onchange event?  http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp?

Comment: Too broad, please elaborate your answer